# Inject views into ItemsControl depending on object type using Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism

I have a service returning an array of type BaseItem. BaseItem has N subtypes. I’m consuming this service in my WPF application (Prism, MVVM) from a view model. In the constructor of this view model I populate an observable collection of type BaseItem:

```
public CurrentViewModel(IDataService dataService) 
{ 
    _dataService = dataService

    var baseItems = _dataService.GetAllItems(); // there are many kinds of BaseItems
    _baseItems = new ObservableCollection<BaseItem>(baseItems.ToList()); 
}
```

So far so good. In my `CurrentView` I have an `ItemsControl` that binds to this collection. In this control I want to render each `BaseItem` by using another `View` (and its view model).

Until now, I can't use `DataTemplateSelector` because I can't define each DataTemplate in it, I'm loading N modules (which contain classes which inherit from `BaseItem`) and PRISM loads them dinamically from an specific folder.

I'm using view Model first approach, what other alternatives do I have to implement the scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693863/inject-views-into-itemscontrol-depending-on-object-type isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: Also please learn [from your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335884/view-injection-inside-itemscontrol) how to write question title and how do not use tags there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply export your datatemplate resources as a resourcedictionary from your moduls with the specific subtype as DataType. i do this with MEF and in my main app merge this resourcedictionarys. now all datatemplates/views are known to WPF and the itemscontrol render every subtype viewmodel like you want.

EDIT:

modul1.dll

```
public class Modul1VM : BaseItemViewModel {}
```

ResourceDictionary in modul1.dll exported with MEF

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local: Modul1VM}">
 <view:Yourmodul1View/>
</DataTemplate>
```

modul2.dll

```
public class Modul2VM : BaseItemViewModel {}
```

ResourceDictionary in modul2.dll exported with MEF

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local: Modul2VM}">
 <view:Yourmodul2View/>
</DataTemplate>
```

your main app

- merge alle exported Resourcedictionarys

app.xaml.cs

```
 [ImportMany("Resourcen", typeof (ResourceDictionary))] 
 private IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> _importResourcen;
```

OnStartup

```
 foreach (var resourceDictionary in _importResourcen)
 {
     this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
 }
```

your itemscontrol just need the collection of BaseItemViewModels as itemssource

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm using MS Unity instead of MEF, but it was so simply to implemented! Just one thing, so in my itemsControl I should an item template selector to find the resource right?

Comment: i would say you dont need a template selector at all. as far as your datatemplates are in the resourcedictionary of your app. wpf knows how to render your subviewmodel objects. thats the way i do it.

Comment: thanks, I got the idea! I while I've implemented through a selector.. so let me change the idea!! You got it!