# View Injection inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism

In my application, I'm dealing with an `ItemControl`. This itemControl receives an ObservableCollection.

As you can see above, BaseItemViewModel is an abstract class. And when my application is launching, `moduleCatalog` loads the modules by discovery.

Each module has a class inherited from BaseItemViewModel

So I can't set the dataTemplates in ItemsControl like this:

```
<DataTemplate> 
    <View:GeneralSettingsView/> 
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate> 
    <View:AdvancedSettingsView/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

What can I do to show the view from the respective view model if I'm using Module Discovery?

Comment: dont know why my working answer is deleted. you have to ask http://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard he did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the ItemTemplateSelector property?

For example, create a content selector class:

```
public class myContentSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            VMBase vm = item as VMBase;

            switch (vm.Type)
            {
                case myType.General:
                    return Application.Current.Resources["GeneralSettings"] as DataTemplate;
                default:
                    return Application.Current.Resources["AdvancedSettings"] as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Create a static resource for it:

```
<local:myContentSelector x:Key="contentSelector" />
```

And set in the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding mySource}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource contentSelector}" />
```

And set your datatemplates to the names:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GeneralSettings" DataType="{x:Type vm:VMBase}"> 
    <View:GeneralSettingsView/> 
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="AdvancedSettings" DataType="{x:Type vm:VMBase}"> 
    <View:AdvancedSettingsView/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Something like that?

Comment: By doing it this way, the hosting module becomes aware of (and linked to) the modules that will be loaded into it, which is completely the opposite of what Prism is intended to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Just one doubt, is there a way to invoke get the resource through the DataType instead the key?

Comment: @Mark If you know a better way I'd like to see it also.